# Wall Insulation- Existing Wall

Tags: drywall, insulation

An external facing wall in my bedroom is not insulated properly and I would like to add some insulation. The wall about 12 feet wide and 8 feet tall. Blow in insulation is unappealing due to cost.

Is there a reason why I should not just open up the drywall, add batt insulation and redo the drywall again? Material cost would be less than $500 but of course will take up a good chunk of my time. Any thoughts deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That can certainly be done. But if it's an old enough building that there is no insulation, you may also be dealing with removing traditional plaster over lath rather than plasterboard, which is a bigger task. (Or even a layer of each,  as I found in one corner of my house.) You'll find that out quickly when you start, though... Or you could do a smaller test area before committing. Note that it's possible.to blow insulation in through holes in the inner wall if preferred; dusty but so is plaster demolition.

Comment: Not only insulation but application of an air barrier (i.e. sealing the joints of or the application of Tyvek or similar material [that blocks air but allows moisture to migrate] to the inside surface of the exterior sheathing ) to prevent movement of air *through* the insulation.

Comment: Depending on your location and the size of the room, adding 2x2s to 2x4 wall studs will give you deeper insulation space.

Comment: Chemicals? Fire resistance? I think you've made unfounded assumptions.  Neither blown fiberglass nor cellulose have those problems. That said, your question is rather vague. The only answer I can give with the information I have is "probably not".

Comment: You are still asking for opinions. As an example, if you were to ask, how to open and close it, it would make it on topic

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly remove the drywall and re-insulate - I have done exactly that.

Make sure to save a chunk of the drywall you remove for coloring matching purposes, if you intend to repaint it the same.

If the drywall was attached with glue, an oscillating tool with a scraper blade will make reasonable work of removing the glue from the studs.